# If element is shown, hide another in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two dropdowns, is there a way to make a if statement for them using only CSS?

Example of what I'm trying to do:
**if dropdown1 has display:block** then **dropdown2 will be forced to have display:none**

Comment: The question is not clear for others to give their solution. please make your question more clear and add your code to explain what you have tried

Comment: Can both dropdowns be hidden? Do you just want to show _at most one_ dropdown? How are these dropdowns being shown — via click?

Comment: I have two dropdowns, I want to create an if statement to hide one of them if the other one has display:block

Comment: sorry, I meant display:none

Comment: Both dropdowns overlap, but one of them is more important, so if the more important one is shown, I want the other one to be hidden.

Comment: You most probably want to use [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) if it shall be CSS only.

Comment: yes, I think it is possible only with css.

Comment: but how can I say in CSS that I want dropdown2 to have display:nove IF dropdown1 has display:block?

Comment: it depends on how your dropdowns are done

Answer (score 3):

Not the most clear question, not the most elegant answer but definitely possible.

```css
#dropdown-1.d-block ~ #dropdown-2 {
  display: none;
}

.d-block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown-1" class="d-block">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>

<select id="dropdown-2">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: this answer is perfect. now to let this work toggle the class of `dblock` to `dropdown-1`